# Display freezes with no load

Tags: boot, display, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 LTS in my Laptop. Sometimes my display freezes with no load, keys not working, only cursor is moving, sound continuously coming.

I have 12 GB RAM, Graphics Driver are Okay, two sessions one guest and another Personal. But when I am inserting external keyboard and pressing keys CTRL+ALT+F2 then I go to Guest session directly where everything works very well although when I try to log in for My personal session everything freezed there.

An help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note Ubuntu 23.04 was **not** a LTS release, with support as per [announcements](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/04/20/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-released/) which states rather clearly "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 9 months for all flavours releasing with 23.04*".  Maybe the LTS was a typo (*I know I type it often after .04*) but your system is only supported until mid-late January 2024, so don't forget to plan your [*release-upgrade*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades)

Comment: Earlier, I was using Ubuntu 22.10 and I was facing same problem that's why I upgraded it to UBUNTU 23.04.